# How do I force a transaction to execute on a certain future block #? (Ethereum, JS API)

Tags: ethereum

I'm trying to send a transaction and have it execute on a certain block. This appears to be possible according to the JS API:

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction

See parameter #2, unless I'm misunderstanding it.

But every time I try to do this, it fails with "invalid address":

```
incrementer.increment.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase}, 28410, function(err, address) {
  if (!err)
    console.log("no err " + address); 
  else
    console.log("err " + address); 
});
```

...whereas removing the block parameter 28410...

```
incrementer.increment.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase}, function(err, address) {
  if (!err)
    console.log("no err " + address); 
  else
    console.log("err " + address); 
});
```

...succeeds just fine.

Anybody know what is going on with this? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 5):

The `web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionObject [,callback])` function has indeed only 2 parameters.

(See here: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/master/lib/web3/methods/eth.js#L177, the optional Callback is implicit).

The text in the wiki is likely a copy & past mistake. I fixed this now, so please don't blame for not having read the documentation :)

NB. I don't see why you wish to target a special block for transaction inclusion. You can never be sure that your transaction is included in a block since this is decided by the miner and not the transaction submitter. If you like to have a deferred execution, you would need to use a Contract.

---

Edit: add reply to comment below as it's a general information.

"Transaction" and "Contract" are 2 things at different levels. When speaking of "Contract", one speaks generally (in the context of Ethereum) of application code defining a logic that is executed either totally or not at all (ensured by the very Blockchain, so no need for a 3rd trusted party, thus "Smart Contract"). This code "lives" on the Blockchain, ie. its code is stored there and has its state/memory there.

A transaction is something you "do" on the Blockchain. When you want to deploy a Contract, you place it (the code) in a transaction object and send it without destination address (to the Blockchain so to speak). The deployment  is executed by a miner and the contract is inserted in the Blockchain. The deployment operation is a transaction.

Executing an Ether transfer is transaction too (basically invoking a simple internal value transfer contract). Invoking and executing a complex "User"-Contract is a transaction, which is also executed by a miner, and the result/outcome is stored on the Blockchain (as part of the currently mined Block). Basic transaction execution has costs (send value, deploy), executing complex contracts as well (cf Gas etc.).

(It's a bit difficult to explain all this all in 2 words. Each time, I re-read the text, I add new sentences ;) I hope this helps.)

Comment: So a new contract is guaranteed to be mined, but transactions are not?

Comment: Also, the reason for including in a specific block is I was hoping to create a cron-like daemon. Instead of hours, minutes, and, it would use the block #.

Comment: Using the Block counter as (cron) timer is not a good idea. It's a bit like counting packets on the network to implement a application software  timing. You need something independent of the network as reference. There a various possibilities with Ethereum and the best solution depends really on what you wish to achieve. Maybe you could discuss your idea on the Ethereum forum. A lot of smart people are there to give you ideas and pointers, and it's not a Q&A site like SO.

Answer (score 4):

The [Ethereum Alarm Clock](http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/) can schedule contract function calls at a certain time or block. It is currently working on mainnet and testnets. You can also deploy it on local network.

> - An Ethereum contract that facilitates scheduling function calls for a specified block in the future.
> - Function calls can be scheduled to be executed against any contract
> - Scheduling can be done by contracts or ethereum account holders.
> - Fully contained within the ethereum network.

The following contract, for example, can delay a payment. [It is example from Ethereum Alarm Clock repository](https://github.com/ethereum-alarm-clock/ethereum-alarm-clock/blob/master/contracts/_examples/DelayedPayment.sol):

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

import "contracts/Interface/SchedulerInterface.sol";

/// Example of using the Scheduler from a smart contract to delay a payment.
contract DelayedPayment {

    SchedulerInterface public scheduler;

    address recipient;
    address owner;
    address public payment;

    uint lockedUntil;
    uint value;
    uint twentyGwei = 20000000000 wei;

    constructor(
        address _scheduler,
        uint    _numBlocks,
        address _recipient,
        uint _value
    )  public payable {
        scheduler = SchedulerInterface(_scheduler);
        lockedUntil = block.number + _numBlocks;
        recipient = _recipient;
        owner = msg.sender;
        value = _value;

        uint endowment = scheduler.computeEndowment(
            twentyGwei,
            twentyGwei,
            200000,
            0,
            twentyGwei
        );

        payment = scheduler.schedule.value(endowment)( // 0.1 ether is to pay for gas, bounty and fee
            this,                   // send to self
            "",                     // and trigger fallback function
            [
                200000,             // The amount of gas to be sent with the transaction.
                0,                  // The amount of wei to be sent.
                255,                // The size of the execution window.
                lockedUntil,        // The start of the execution window.
                twentyGwei,    // The gasprice for the transaction (aka 20 gwei)
                twentyGwei,    // The fee included in the transaction.
                twentyGwei,         // The bounty that awards the executor of the transaction.
                twentyGwei * 2     // The required amount of wei the claimer must send as deposit.
            ]
        );

        assert(address(this).balance >= value);
    }

    function () public payable {
        if (msg.value > 0) { //this handles recieving remaining funds sent while scheduling (0.1 ether)
            return;
        } else if (address(this).balance > 0) {
            payout();
        } else {
            revert();
        }
    }

    function payout()
        public returns (bool)
    {
        require(block.number >= lockedUntil);

        recipient.transfer(value);
        return true;
    }

    function collectRemaining()
        public returns (bool) 
    {
        owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

The easiest way to programatically schedule a transaction is to use [@ethereum-alarm-clock/lib](https://github.com/ethereum-alarm-clock/lib). This is JS library with TypeScript types (easier to work with).

Here's text tutorial how to use this library: https://github.com/ethereum-alarm-clock/ethereum-alarm-clock/wiki/Integration-using-EAC-JavaScript-library

And here's video tutorial: https://youtu.be/DY0QYDQG4lw